# Extending Windows and Spotlight and other OS search

Tags: android, search, windows-7, ios4

I want to have something like this:

1. User types a search query in the default search bar provided by the OS. OSes I want to support are: Win 7, OS X, Android, iOS.
2. Somehow the OS's search bar passes the search query to my application
3. My application looks for results in our web server using HTTP APIs
4. We pass the results to the OSes' search. It shows them.

Is it possible to achieve this functionality in:

- Windows 7
- OS X
- Android
- iOS (I don't think it should be possible in iOS, just kept it for the sake of completeness)

I am mostly concerned about the extend-ability of each of these OSes' search bar.

Comment: Seems you want to to create another google ! BTW good question +1

Answer (score 1):

for Windows 7 you can do this by creating a Federated Search provider. This is pretty simple and very well documented. See here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd742958%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

For extending the Finder in MacOS: I don't know either; that is how I stumbled on your question in the first place!